# Make files available for download

Tags: html

I am working on a page where one can view the contents of one (or more) text-files. I would also like a download button which allows for a download of those files. I would like to stick these files in an archive before downloading.

What I would like to avoid is having a copy of both the files & the archive on my server (update one but not the other .. etc).

How should I go about this?

- Should I keep both the files & the archive anyway
- Do I create the archive on the fly (i.e. when the user hits the download button)
- Do I extract the contents of the archive each time the page is loaded
- Are there any libraries that you know of that already do this sort of thing (I have searched but didn't come up with anything useful)
- A backend strategy that somehow prevents a discrepancy between files & archive
- ....

Thanks

Comment: In my point of view the 'archive' would always be the original file. The user should be able to see and edit your original file but not save it. He can however download his version of the file. I know this doesnt solve anything but it might make the situation a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP as backend(Some server side language is needed to create zips on the fly) and create zips based on user requests.

`$files_to_zip = array(
    'preload-images/1.jpg',
    'preload-images/2.jpg',
    'preload-images/5.jpg',
    'kwicks/ringo.gif',
    'rod.jpg',
    'reddit.gif'
);
//if true, good; if false, zip creation failed
$result = create_zip($files_to_zip,'my-archive.zip');`

Further information http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

Comment: I didn't explain that properly I suppose, but I can use perl, php, nodejs, jquery, ... if needed .. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Then I guess this will work fine, as I used to have a similar functionality for downloading images.